Bug with Laravel Eloquent query buldier
I found a weird situation when nesting in a query a where with a orWhereNull.
The result is returning rows with values that are neither null nor correct
This is the code:
$query = Document::where("active", true)->where("type_id", $document_type->id);
if($selected) {
    $query->where(function($q) use($selected) {
        return $q->where("origen_id", $selected->id)
            ->orWhereNull("origen_id");
    });
}
$result = $query->orderBy("origen_id")->get();

When debuggin, $query->toSql() returns:
select * from documents where active = ? and type_id = ? and (origen_id = ? or origen_id is null)
The values of the wheres are correct:
wheres1
wheres2
when I run this query, it returns only one result, but the $query->get() is returning 2, one of them, with a origen_id diferent than $selected->id (and not null)
This is a really weird thing, and I'm not sure how to get the espected results, bcose the generated query is OK

Check that if($selected) is true

So.... this was a 2 part problem.
From testing reported a problem (a non-existent one), so when y run the query and return one value (instead of the 2 showed in the app) I assume that there was some kind of problem somewere.
Remeber, always check and double-check to witch DataBase you are pointing.... really, you never know.
